# Creating extension for multiple Exception

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

Could someone help me create a simple extension for exception? So that I can always use anywhere.
I'm always using exception in all of my process.

Here's the exception that I always used:

```
try
{

}catch (HttpRequestException ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
 catch (KeyNotFoundException ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
 catch (JsonException ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
 catch (InvalidDataException ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
 catch (Exception ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
```

Comment: This code is entirely redundant as written and only needs one catch

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Could you enlightened me? because I'm not expert of handling the exception.

Comment: The following will catch all the types of exceptions `catch (Exception ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }` the other catch blocks are not adding anything more than this line does. You are saying, on this exception do something, on another exception do the same thing, and on every other exception (including the previous ones), do the same thing.

Comment: Ah so I only needed the Exception only? I thought it can't catch the jsonexception and keynotfound

Comment: `Exception`, will catch all managed exceptions, including those

Comment: Alright i get it. Thank you so much for your time,

Comment: @zacky yes, you need just single exception like this : catch (Exception ex) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }

Comment: @mhkarami97 yeah like what Michael said. I already removed other exception

Comment: @mhkarami97 so the I don't also needed to catch "TaskCanceledException"? for cancellationtokensource

Comment: If someone feels like answering this, maybe you could show the approach for an action to wrap common exceptions, but also explain that only one exception block is needed for this code.

Comment: @zacky, you need just to catch "TaskCanceledException" if you want do other work with it, if you need just LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message) , so it's not need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you still have the same pattern, you can refactor and create one or more methods to encapsulate the `try catch` and its variances.

For example:

```
static public bool TryCatch(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    return true;
  }
  catch ( HttpRequestException ex ) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
  catch ( KeyNotFoundException ex ) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
  catch ( JsonException ex ) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
  catch ( InvalidDataException ex ) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
  catch ( Exception ex ) { LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message); }
  return false;
}
```

*Usage*

```
bool result = TryCatch(() =>
{
  //
});
if ( result )
  DoSomeThing();
else
  DoAnotherThing;

TryCatch(SomeMethod);
```

The bool is for convenience and can be ommited.

This limits the use because of the method signature that takes an `Action` as a parameter but you can create some overloads if really needed...

For example I regularly use:

```
static public bool TryCatch(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ex.Manage(ShowExceptionMode.None);
    return false;
  }
}

static public bool TryCatchManage(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    return true;
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    ex.Manage();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Where the `Manage` methods analyses the exception from the stack to get information like class name, method name, source code file name and line number, shows a message and logs to a roll over file.

Note: As said by @MichaelRandall, all the catch in your code can be written as

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
  LogsHelper.Error(ex.Message);
}
```

Unless you want to manage each case like exposed by @Tân.

Answer (score 1):

When you use try-catch block with multiple exceptions, you just need to catch the exceptions that you know it may occur.

The last exception should be used in order to catch another exception that you may be unexpected.

```
try
{
    // do something with http request and get erorr...
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    // the error relates to HttpRequest

    return "Cannot connect to server...";
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
{
    // the error relates to some key in some collection
    // that couldn't be found

    return "Key is not valid...";
}
catch (JsonException ex)
{
    // the error relates to JSON
    // while you try to parse, serialize, deserialize...

    return "Cannot parse to JSON...";
}
catch (InvalidDataException ex)
{
    // the error relates to your data stream
    // it may be invalid format

    return "Invalid data format..."
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // other exception/error
    // DivideByZeroException
    // NullReferenceException
    // SqlException
    // ...

    return "Failed to do something..."
}
```

BTW, you can do something/return some data with some specific message...